# 'ifconfig eth0 up' does not restore connection

Tags: debian, kali-linux

(I am running Kali (Debian) on a VM.)

I had been experiencing problems with changing my computer's MAC address, as whenever i try:

```
root@kali:~# macchanger -r eth0
Current MAC:   08:00:27:3b:23:a1 (CADMUS COMPUTER SYSTEMS)
Permanent MAC: 08:00:27:3b:23:a1 (CADMUS COMPUTER SYSTEMS)
[ERROR] Could not change MAC: interface up or insufficient permissions: Device or resource busy.
```

I then fixed this by using the following commands:

```
sudo -i
ifconfig eth0 down
macchanger -r eth0
ifconfig eth0 up
```

Only, whenever i type the last command, *ifconfig eth0 up* , my connection is still lost. I cant connect to Internet, cant ping any servers or anything of the sort.

Edit: Using the Adapter Type 'Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop' allows me to change my MAC address without having to use any other commands, however, when it is set that way, i also have no connection. (Which is why I am currently using the Adapter Type 'PCnet-FAST-III' attached to 'Bridged Adapter')

Comment: Seems like you have to run `dhclient -v -r eth0 && dhclient -v eth0`

Comment: Given that this is stuff that is explicitly called out, with emphasis, in Arch doco, I am saddened to see that people think that this is an "unclear or not useful" question for a Debian user to ask.

Comment: often it takes a while for picking up the new MAC...

Comment: run `ifconfig eth0` to check if changes are aproved to interface, and ping your gateway ip to test if interface is working correctly.

Comment: try `systemctl restart networking`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you're just not picking up an IP address, because your DHCP client is not running or needs to be told that there is a new MAC address or needs to be restarted after a MAC address change.

On my machine I would try running `dhcpcd -t 10 eth0` to start up a DHCP client but this is not a Debian machine.  Debian on-line manuals indicate that on Debian 9 the command is instead named [`dhcpcd5`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/dhcpcd5/dhcpcd5.8.en.html) or [`dhclient`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/isc-dhcp-client/dhclient.8.en.html).

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will be an answer as I answered the initial question I had,
I finally got internet connectivity to finally work while using Adapter Type 'Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop', what I had to do was go into `crontab -e`
and remove the command `@reboot macchanger -r eth0` as I found out whenever I try changing the MAC address, its the cause of the internet losing connectivity. I am pretty sure using `dhclient -v -r eth0 && dhclient -v eth0` did help, as i previously did remove `@reboot macchanger -r eth0` from crontab earlier with no effect.